# How to automatically invoke method inside controller in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I recently learned about Angular.js. Here I integrate Angular.js with Beego (Go Framework) to develop Single Page Application. I confuse how to automatically invoke method inside Angular controller?

Here's my angular controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('BarangMasukController', ['$scope', '$http', 'myServices', function ($scope, $http, myServices) {
        var initializeTask = function () {
            myServices.testAPI()
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.Sa = response.data.S;
                    $scope.Da = response.data.D;
                    console.log("Sa"+$scope.Sa);
                    console.log("Da"+$scope.Da);
                });
        }
        initializeTask();         
}]);
```

My angular service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('myServices', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        //testapi
        testAPI: function () {
            return $http.get('/myapi');
        },
    };
}]);
```

my angular routes:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/testAPI", {
      templateUrl: "static/views/penjualan/manage_penjualan.tpl",
      controller: 'BarangMasukController' 
    })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  });
```

As you can see, I need to call method initializeTask() manually in my controller. The problem arise when there are multiple methods inside my controller. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your methods to be automatically invoked, you can make use of Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) from JavaScript which is a function that runs as soon as it is defined.

```
(function () {
    // logic here
})();
```

See the Mozilla developer guide for more [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

If you want to place all your initialization logics in a method and if you are using `components` then you can make use of angularjs `$onInit()` lifecycle hook which will automatically get invoked after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized. More info can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).